# Using get/set Computed property with mapState, mapMutation in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, computed-properties, v-model

I have the following computed property using a Vuex module called `main`:

```
computed: {
  foo: {
    get(){
      return this.$store.state.main.foo;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit("main/foo", value);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use the `get`/`set` pattern because I want to use `v-model="foo"`. Having to talk to `$store` directly is all very verbose. Is there an easier way using `mapState`, `mapMutation` or even `createNamespacedHelpers`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you to try **[vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields)** module, which contains a `mapFields`helper method helps you setup getter and setter dynamically.